# SQL Select With Multiple And

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I've got a very long sql statement that I'm trying to add some AND conditions to but it's not working.

Here is my statement:

```
if($cat=="att") { $sqlCatC = "INNER JOIN yt_att_data CAT
    ON CAT.busID = R.id AND CAT.subcatID = 5 AND CAT.subcatID = 136 AND CAT.deleted = 0"; }

//Get RegionInfo busID based on region, approved
    $sql= "SELECT DISTINCT CAT.busID,R.id,companyName,membershipID,addressID,city,logo,descriptionShort FROM yt_Business_RegInfo R
    $sqlReg
    INNER JOIN yt_Business_Seasons S
    ON R.id = S.busID AND S.deleted = 0
    INNER JOIN yt_Business_Address A
    ON R.addressID = A.id
    INNER JOIN yt_Business_Membership M
    ON R.membershipID = M.id AND M.approved = 1
    $sqlCatC
    WHERE R.deleted = 0
    ORDER BY R.companyName ASC LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

It's in the top $sqlCatC that I'm trying to add an AND condition of where CAT.subcatID is equal to 5 and 136.  It works with checking for a single CAT.subcatID but not for two.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: For an individual row `CAT.subcatID` can't be both `5` and `136` at the same time. Do you need `OR` or are you looking for [relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) (in which case you need `OR`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`)?

Comment: How is it not working ? Do you get an error ? Or wrong results ? If so, how is the results wrong ? I suspect you perhaps want an OR instead of AND.

Comment: If I use OR then it only shows the record with the chosen subcatID 5 or 136.  I need it to show the company record that has both selected.  It's basically a company record that has certain criteria checked off and I need to show it if both of these are checked.

Comment: In that case you need `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT subcatID)=2` in addition to using `OR` (or `IN`)

Comment: @Martin - Thanks.  This is what I've tried but I'm getting a mysql error.  'INNER JOIN yt_att_data CAT
 ON CAT.busID = R.id AND CAT.deleted = '0' AND CAT.subcatID IN(5,136) GROUP BY CAT.subcatID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CAT.subcatID)=2'

Answer (score 2):

Use the `IN` keyword like this:

```
CAT.subcatID IN(5,136)
```

to replace your two ANDs.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the edit :) I was doing the same and realized that the answer has already been edited.

Answer (score 1):

The subcatID can not be 5 and 136 at  a time you have to use OR instead of AND.

Change it to and try

```
ON CAT.busID = R.id AND 
(CAT.subcatID = 5 OR CAT.subcatID = 136) 
AND CAT.deleted = 0";
```

OR you can make it short using IN

```
 ON CAT.busID = R.id AND 
 CAT.subcatID IN ('5','136') 
    AND CAT.deleted = 0";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an AND condition applied when you are equating the same column to two different values.
Use an OR condition.

Change the $sqlCatC to as below:

```
$sqlCatC = "INNER JOIN yt_att_data CAT  ON CAT.busID = R.id AND (CAT.subcatID = 5 OR CAT.subcatID = 136) AND CAT.deleted = 0";
```

Comment: The problem is I only want the record to show up if both of the subcatIDs are in my table.  The subcatIDs are criteria based on a company record.  For instance the DB table looks like this:  id busID subcatID, 8000 - 845 - 5, 8001 - 845 - 136